# is there any library for animation that handles app background/foreground issues

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

When we go for uiview animation when app goes to background and comes to foreground there is a issue of animation [pause and resume](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1673/_index.html) and it doesn't work well if there is POD based view is used

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

    }];
```

is there any better animation library that handles application background and foreground thing with respect to animation